# Chrome extension remembers the tab from which a tab was openned

Tags: tabs, google-chrome-extension

I often open many tabs in Chrome, especially when I read wikipedia. The problem is that when I read through an article in wikipedia and want to go back to continue reading the previous article, which leads me to the article I just finished reading, I may forget which article (or tab) lead me to the current article/tab, I am wondering if there is such a Chrome extension that will navigate me back to the previous tab. If not, I think I will write such extension by myself.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use one of the [`chrome.tabs`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html) methods to get a [`Tab`-type](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#type-Tab) object. This object contains the property `openerTabId`, which holds an integer which refers to the opener tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such extensions already exist.
Here are two examples:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nikomkkhhpfoeamojhhgpfkpkdlfhfii
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cldflinjcjehpjddjkohganfpjlnbpem